# Migrations issue in Cpanel postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, cpanel

I have a query regarding Cpanel.

I had created python application with using Django Framework and Postgresql as database and I am facing issue while migrating the database. Below is the error:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Search will not find them.

Answer (score 0):

Add or edit the following line in your postgresql.conf :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Add the following line as the first line of pg_hba.conf. It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password:

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Restart Postgresql after adding this with service PostgreSQL restart or the equivalent command for your setup.

([Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host))

Comment: path: /etc/postgresql/9.1_or_your_version/main/postgresql.conf. You can also use `psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'`